# Java based Swing Browser should support JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, swing, swt

In my company, I am implementing a java based html browser. I found a lot of tools to generate complete browsers only in Swing which are looking like Mozilla. But I was not able to find a browser which supports JavaScript. The browser I will implement should execute JavaScript inside the HTML sides.

Do you know of a tool that supports this? Or do you know of a parser which pairs the javascript to something I can use inside the html browser?

I know that the eclipse plugins can handle javascript, but I can not use AWT in my project.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at [Lobo](https://github.com/lobobrowser/LoboBrowser).  It sounds like just want you want.  It has a HTML Renderer and parser, and some support for Javascript.  If it's missing a feature of Javascript that you need, it seems like it would easier to contribute to Lobo, instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Will you please tell me that how to implement this?

Comment: Original link currntly does not work and lobo can be found here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xamj/

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to build this yourself.  Fortunately, there are a number of open source [javascript engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines) you might be able to adapt.

Comment: add the moment the html sides are shown by using C++ and a firefox plugin, but i should use the existing html sides which including javascript.
I have no choice, i have to show html with javascript.

Comment: I'm not saying don't do it:  I'm saying find someone else that's already done it and use that.

Answer (score 1):

*In my company, I am implementing a java based html browser.*

Good God, why?

That said, [this page at java.net](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/05/24/html-pt1.html) discusses some options; you could search it more extensively.